# document.body.appendChild() will work but not when I try to append to a specific element in the body

Tags: javascript, html

I have this function which I call onclick whenever a checbox is clicked, but for some reason I cant add it to the document. Ive changed the last line to a bunch of different things, but for some reason the only way I can add it to the document is to use document.body.appendChild(frag);

I want to be able to add it into a specific place, so I tried to get the target of the event by id. There are a lot more boxes so I wanted to get the ID of the box being clicked and add the elements underneath it, and my code had been working to append the children, just nothing actually showed up... I included one of the checkboxes in my html.

```
<form id="lang" class="poll" onsubmit="langCheck()">
            <h1 class="background ulin center">What programming languages do you know?</h1>
            <input class="lbox" id = "box1" type="checkbox" value="Assembly" onclick="addSelect(this)">Assembly<br>
</form>

    function addSelect(e) {

      var target = document.getElementById(e.id);
      var lol = e.id;
      var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();

      var select = document.createElement('select');
      var optgroup = document.createElement('optgroup');
      var options = [
        document.createElement('option'),
        document.createElement('option'),
        document.createElement('option')
      ];

      //Define content for options
      optgroup.label = "Level of expertise?";
      options[0].value = "Beginner";
      options[1].value = "Intermediate";
      options[2].value = "Expert";

      frag.appendChild(select);
      select.appendChild(optgroup);
      //add all options to the optgroup node

      options.forEach(function(element) {
        optgroup.appendChild(element);
      });

      document.body.querySelector('#box1').appendChild(frag);
    }
```

Comment: inputs do not have children..... So how can you append to an input?

Answer (score 0):

Input elements can't have children. If you want the fragment to appear after the input, you would need to insert it into the document as a sibling of the element. Unfortunately for HTMLElement, there is no built in "insertAfter", only insertBefore. you need to insert the new element before the element's nextSibling. If there isn't a next sibling, it's safe to assume the element is the last child (unless it isn't in the dom), so you can then just append it.

Something like this should do the trick:

```
function insertAfter(newElement,refElement){
   if(refElement.nextSibling)refNode.parentElement.insertBefore(newElement,refElement.nextSibling);
   else refNode.parentElement.appendChild(newElement);
 }
 insertAfter(document.getElementById('#box1'),frag);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by another way, you need to change the visibility of elements when the checkbox is checked, so you can addEventLister to checkbox and change the style of elements when it triggers the event.

```js
const checkBox = document.getElementById('box1')

checkBox.addEventListener('change', function(){
  const elements = [...document.getElementsByClassName("visibility")]  
  if(this.checked){
    elements.forEach(element => {element.style.display="initial"})   
  }else{
    elements.forEach(element => {element.style.display="none"})  
  }
})
```

```html
<form id="lang" class="poll" onsubmit="langCheck()">
    <h1 class="background ulin center">What programming languages do you know?</h1>
    <input class="lbox" id = "box1" type="checkbox" value="Assembly">Assembly<br>
    <p class="visibility" style="display:none"><input name="level" type="radio" id="radioButton1"> Expert</p>
    <p class="visibility" style="display:none"><input name="level" type="radio" id="radioButton2"> Middle</p>
    <p class="visibility" style="display:none"><input name="level" type="radio" id="radioButton3"> Beginner</p>
  </form>
```